# The correct place for a listener

Tags: spring-boot

I have a REST Web server. I use spring-boot. The server listens to some kind of events that can occur on a remote machine (regular web request) and on the local machine (where server run) both. 
My question is where I have to define the listener for local events?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MApplication.class, args);
        listenr.subscribe(new Handler())// call back method will call 
                                        // once in a while
    }
}
```

Is it correct place for the listener?

Comment: Clearly you have not ever used spring boot. Lookup a general getting started with spring boot tutorial

Comment: Your question is nothing to do with Spring Boot. And there are many ways to handle such event, e.g. via web service, message queue and so on.

Comment: I need the server to listen for a remote client but the same event can occur on the local machine(server machine) and i have to handle it too.